# Vue - If class exist on router-page then display another class

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

Im new to Vue and struggling with a simple task, in some router-pages i have a class "1" and if that exist i want another class "2" to be displayed.

I installed jQuery first on main.js like this:

```
import jQuery from 'jquery'
global.jQuery = jQuery
```

Then im using this code in the app.vue at the  tag but the page goes white, maybe i need to write something before?

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
}

setTimeout(function(){
    document.body.className="";
},200);

// The code below is the one
$('.1').toggle($('.2').length > 0);
</script>
```

So i tried instead pasting the same line on the bottom of main.js, the page loads in but the code dosnt do anything. What am i doing wrong :(? Is that line i found javascript or jquery?

Comment: I would like to see more of what(how) you are trying to achieve here. I think you might not use Vue for what it is. Personally, I would never combine Vue with Jquery, simply because Vue has a totally different workflow than Jquery. You would generally want Vue to be in charge of the states in order to take advantage of Vue.

Comment: The class `1`, how/when is this applied to the given element? Is that coming from some other Jquery thing? If so, and you are in charge of it, I would recommend you to make Vue add the class and set a data attribute. This way, you are doing it the "Vue way".

Comment: I really appreciate your time for answering. I would not mind at all using vue, i just dont know how the code should be? No the class one is just a regular <div class="1">. In short i want to view content in 6 of 20 router-pages. So i used that content in app.vue which applies for all 20 router pages, and then from here im stuck. Im thinking something like make css hidden, and on the other 6 router-page i have a class "1" at the top, so if vue/jquery detect that it also changes the "2" css to visible.